# What is the worst case runtime for Linear search and Binary search?

Tags: binary-search, asymptotic-complexity, linear-search

I believe the worst case asymptotic complexities for Linear search and Binary Search are O(n) and O(lgn) respectively.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Can you find examples of cases that trigger these run times?

Comment: I am going to try to look for that, but at the moment, I do not have any.